# Cannot stop defunct docker-containe

Tags: docker

I had stoped the docker-deamon, but there still docker processes running, kill -9 PID or killall -9 containerd didn't work. When I restart the docker, some error occurs.

[docker-deamon status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE2oy.png)

[defunct docker-containe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEIdT.png)

[start docker-deamon error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABlkc.png)

[messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6wSs.png)

docker version:
Client:
 Version:      18.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   9ee9f40
 Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:20:16 2018
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: I  solved  it  with  {kill 1  }

Answer (score -1):

See topic [51881286](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51881286/fail-to-run-docker-while-building-an-image) where the problem has been solved previously. The post installation steps for Linux should be done.