# How to run Docker commands during Dockerfile build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to run docker commands inside `Dockerfile` to build image. My project uses docker on build jar phase.
My problem is that I fail to run `docker build .` on following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM docker
RUN docker ps
```

I receive following error: `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

I know that docker build has many limitations, but I want to bypass it somehow...

This is my sample project code, which uses docker containers for integration tests: https://github.com/modestukasai/spring-boot-testcontainers-docker

Thanks a lot!

I have already raised some issues in:

https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/1110

https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/1112

https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-run-docker-commands-during-dockerfile-build/66249

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fail to run docker while building an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51881286/fail-to-run-docker-while-building-an-image)

Comment: What are you ultimately hoping will be in the built image?

Comment: Do you have the docker daemon running on your local machine?